# Barra de progresso com AJAX no forEach - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando utilizar uma barra de progresso do bootstrap 4, mas não consigo atualizar o progresso a cada requisição que faço dentro do laço forEach. A partir do arquivo JSON que recebo, cada objeto possui dados para fazer uma requisição POST, e a cada loop, independente da requisição ter retornado erro ou não, eu queria que a barra de progresso fosse atualizada. Tentei trocar a flag "async=true", mas assim o código fora do forEach é executado antes do AJAX terminar a execução, o que não é desejável. Do jeito que o código está a seguir, notei que os valores são atualizados no HTML, mas o estilo só é atualizado depois que todas as requisições são feitas. Segue o código (alguns trechos foram ocultados):

```
function efetueDisparo() {
            
    let erros = [];
    let progresso = 0;
    let count = 0;

    alvos["mailing"].forEach(alvo => {
        count++;

        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(monteBody(alvo)),
            headers: header,
            url: "url",
        }).fail(function(textStatus) {
            erros.push({
                "erro": textStatus["responseJSON"],
                "alvo": alvo["Telefone"]
            });
        }).always(function() {
            progresso = Math.round((count * 100) / alvos["mailing"].length);
            atualizaValorBarraProgresso($("#barra-progresso .progress-bar"), progresso);                
        });
    });

    if (erros.length > 0) {
        abraModalBaixarRelatorio(erros);
    }
}

function atualizaValorBarraProgresso(barraProgresso, valor) {
    barraProgresso.attr("style", `width: ${valor}%`);
    barraProgresso.attr("aria-valuenow", `${valor}`);
}
```

Barra de progresso no HTML:

```
<div id="barra-progresso" class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">0%</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu valor de progresso está sendo definido de forma equivocada, o objetivo é chegar com a barra em 100%, então você deve definir de quanto em quanto a barra vai aumentar usando a conta 100 dividido pela quantidade de itens do forEach que atualiza a informação da barra.

Fiz um código usando setInterval ao invés do ajax síncrono que você usou, para que o funcionamento possa ser visto aqui no botão executar, mas a ideia do funcionamento é a mesma para o seu caso.

```js
function efetueDisparo() {            
    let progresso = 0;
    let alvosMailingForEachLength = 5;
    let passos = (100 / alvosMailingForEachLength);
    let interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        if (progresso >= 100) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            atualizaValorBarraProgresso($('.progress-bar'), 100);
        }    
        atualizaValorBarraProgresso($('.progress-bar'), progresso);
        progresso += passos;
    }, 1000);
}

function atualizaValorBarraProgresso(barraProgresso, valor) {
    barraProgresso.attr("style", `width: ${valor}%`);
    barraProgresso.attr("aria-valuenow", `${valor}`);
    barraProgresso.html(`${valor}%`);
}

efetueDisparo();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Porém fiz da forma que indicou e o comportamento continua o mesmo. O cálculo do progresso está ok, se coloco um `console.log(valor)` é apresentado os valores no console enquanto o ajax faz seu processo, até monitorei o html e os atributos são alterados. Mas, pelo o que parece o problema pode estar (não tenho certeza) no bootstrap, o estilo só é atualizado depois que o ajax conclui todas as requisições, a barra começa no 0% e já vai direto pro valor 100%.